# return a list of objects ordered by number of items in navigation property with linq to entity

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a `context` with two entities: one `Authority` to many `Reports` (each report has one authority but every authority can have many reports).

I have navigational properties in each of the entities to point to the other entity.

I am trying to write a query to return a list of authorities that is sorted by the amount of reports it has. Since `Authority` entity has the `Reports` navigation property which is a list of reports I guess i can ask how many reports are in the list.

Is this possible ? I am new to Linq2Entities and i tried to find an example to do that but couldnt find. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want something like:

```
var query = context.Authority.OrderBy(auth => auth.Reports.Count());
```

(Possibly `OrderByDescending` instead.)

Comment: Yes this works, and is very simple. still surprised of the great capabilities of this framework. Thank you.